# Castle.Windsor CollectionResolver and Ordering of Components

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

We use the CollectionResolver in Castle.Windsor (3.1) for injecting a set of components. The order of those is relevant. Currently we use a Position property on the service for ordering them.

As we use the same master component in different applications with a different set of components, the position property is a maintenance burden. It implies knowledge of the components on each other. Also the single component should not know about others.

We want something like registering multiple `IComparer<Type>` for specific service type to control the order of the injected components.

Is there a simple (predefined) way to do this in Castle.Windsor or has anybody done something like this before?

Example of what we want to replace:

```
interface IService
{
   bool Do();
   int Position { get; } // <= This should be kicked!
}

class Master
{
   private readonly IService[] _services;

   public Master(IService[] services)
   {
       // Master should not care about ordering also,
       // but injecting a sorter would be acceptable
       _services = services.OrderBy(s => s.Position).ToArray();
   }

   public void Do()
   {
       foreach(var service in _services)
       {
          if(!service.Do())
             break;
       }
    }
}
```

We want something like the above without Position using a component like this:

```
class OrderService : IComparer<Type>
{       
   public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
   {
      if(typeof(MoreImportantComponent) == x)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can affect the order of services using an `IHandlersFilter` implementation

```
public class ServiceHandlersFilter : IHandlersFilter
{
    private readonly List<Type> sortOrder = new List<Type>
                                                {
                                                   { typeof(Service1) },
                                                   { typeof(Service2) },
                                                   { typeof(Service3) },
                                                };

    public bool HasOpinionAbout(Type service)
    {
        return service == typeof(IService);
    }

    public IHandler[] SelectHandlers(Type service, IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        return handlers
            .OrderBy(h => sortOrder.IndexOf(h.ComponentModel.Implementation))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

You may want the sort order to be determined more elegantly, for example, by the components themselves. If that is the case, check out this [`RespectOrderDirectivesHandlersFilter`](https://github.com/mookid8000/RespectOrderDirectivesHandlersFilter) implementation. [As per mookid's blog post](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/2295) on the filter, you can attribute your `IService` implementations with the `ExecutesBeforeAttribute` and `ExecutesAfterAttribute` attributes to imply order of execution relative to each other.